# How to simulate mouse clicks?

Tags: vb.net, mouse, simulate

I was wondering how to create a sort of auto clicker using VB.NET.

I would basicly have the click coordinates pre-defined and the clicks, which would have to be separated by delays I guess since I want more than one to happen periodically, would happen outside of the application window (I read this envolves extra system hooks?).

The only code I have been able to find is related to clicks on the application window, which is not what I am looking for.

**In short:** I want to click a button on the app window, which would initiate a number of clicks on certain pre-defined screen coordinates.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this discussion on social.msdn: [Simulate a mouse click in a program](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/e79d4501-b3d9-4e37-9b70-966105e09ab1/).

Uses winapi: `SetCursorPos`, `GetCursorPos` and `mouse_event`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to P/Invoke into Windows to accomplish this.

Have a look at the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using automate the program,that program have some tabindex in order to relevant control.then you can use;

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
```

it is more accurate on desktop application